# Equivalent of refetchEvents in FullCalendar V4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In earlier versions of fullcalendar I had used this :

```
$('#Calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

to refetch my events on a button or after I close a form.

What is the equivalent of this call in `FullCalendar V4`?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
See the comments, as of v4 you cannot access the calendar via jQuery anymore.

According to the docs, the function still exists:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents

You can simply do

```
calendar.refetchEvents()
```

whereas `calendar` is the instance that you get when initializing the calendar.

---

*PS:*
On google, you can limit the search by typing `site:fullcalendar.io refetchEvents` - with that search it was very easy to find the information about refetching events with v4.

Comment: i have tried $('#Calendar').getEventSources()[0].refetch(); but it is showing an error getEventSources is not a function. Also when i try calendar.refetchEvents() it says same thing not a function.

Comment: Probably you don't have the acutal object by using `$('#Calendar')`. Maybe check in the console what `$('#Calendar')` has. In Vue.js, you can use `getApi()` to get the actual API object that then has functions like `refetchEvents`.

Comment: `$('#Calendar')` for anything will not work because, as of version 4, fullCalendar is not a JQuery object anymore (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3). You should remove this part from your answer. `calendar.refetchEvents()` is correct though. P.S. you can also do `calendar.getEventSources()` if you wanted to get specific event sources. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventSources . So to revise the first part of your answer, you could write `calendar.getEventSources()[0].refetch();` - very similar, really, just a different way to get the calendar object.

Comment: When i use calendar.getEventSources()[0].refetch(); i get TypeError: calendar.getEventSources is not a function

Comment: @OlumideOrukotan maybe your variable is out of scope of something. It's hard to know when you don't show the code in context. Please edit your original question to show an example which would reproduce the issue you're experiencing. Then we have more chance to help you.

Comment: Hello ADyson should i be able to use calendar.refetchEvents() from the webconsole and see it refresh the calendar?